# How to detect if a long type is actually NULL?

Tags: java, hibernate, nullpointerexception, long-integer

We have a nullable (type long) column (named referral) in our MySQL database. We use hibernate for ORM.

I am trying to get the value of the column for a given member. Some are null, and if its not, its an id that points to another member whose is the referrer.

The problem is in the java code I am trying to detect if that member's column is null, if not, do something.

```
String referrerAffiliateId = Long.toString(member.getReferral());
if (referrerAffiliateId != null){
    //do something
}
```

member.getReferral() returns the value (type long) of the referral column. Some of those columns are null and some are not.

The above code compiles fine, but I get a nullPointerException when I call the method on a user whose referral column is null.

How do I properly do a detection on this?

Thanks in advance!

**Full Answer:**

Thanks to @Marcelo for the best correct answer.

Here is the code in its final state:

```
Long referrerAffiliateId = member.getReferral();
if (referrerAffiliateId != null) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: What's the return type of `member.getReferral()`?

Comment: I assume you mean `Long` since a `long` is a primitive type and is not possible to have it be null. `Long` can be null though. Check the return value of `getReferral()` directly and do not attempt to convert it to a string.

Comment: Based on the comments and your responses, I'd say it's time for an actual stack trace to see where they error really is occurring. I suspect there's something inside getReferral() that is auto-unboxing and causing an NPE. The Source for getReferral() may also be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `member.getReferral()` returns a `Long`, use:

```
if (member.getReferral() != null)
```

In Hibernate, if you want to be able to detect nullability in a property, you must not use *primitive types*, because they will always have a default value `0` for longs.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't return "Long", it returns "long", which as I understand it, is not nullable where "Long" can be.

Comment: @Dale If you want to detect nullability for the referral property using Hibernate, you must change the data type of the property to Long. Otherwise, member.getReferral() will return 0 when the column value is null.

Comment: I chose this solution because the answer uses less code, is cleaner, and cause @Marcelo made the suggestion about the data type change in hibernate.

Answer (score 4):

The exception probably comes from `Long.toString()`, try checking the value before converting to a string:

```
Long ref = member.getReferral();
if (ref == null) {
  // Do something...
} else {
  String referrerAffiliateId = Long.toString(ref);
  // ...
}
```

Comment: As per OP `member.getReferral()` returns long not Long.

Comment: You will not get an exception anymore, but you will never detect nullability of the column.

Answer (score 4):

Change

```
String referrerAffiliateId = Long.toString(member.getReferral());
if (referrerAffiliateId != null){
    //do something
}
```

To:

```
if (member.getReferral() != null){

    String referrerAffiliateId = Long.toString(member.getReferral());
    //do something
}
```

It's likely that you're getting the `NullPointerException` when you call `Long.toString()` with a null parameter.

Answer (score 0):

*use Below code:*

```
    Long ref = member.getReferral();
    String referrerAffiliateId = null;
    if(ref != null){
    referrerAffiliateId = Long.toString(ref); 
    }
```

Comment: OP said that `member.gerReferral()` returns a primitive `long`, and specifically not a `Long`.